# CKFinder issue Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined with CKEditor 5 - Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, ckfinder, ckeditor5

I'm trying to integrate CKFinder in Vue js application. But facing this issue **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined**.

I'm following the [official documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html) for CKEditor5 / CKFinder for Vue js.

Here the ckfinder configuration.

```
    ckfinder: {
        // Define the CKFinder configuration (if necessary).
        options: {
            resourceType: 'Images'
        },
    }
```

Here's the complete error message shown in the browser console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined
    at CKFinderCommand.execute (ckfindercommand.js?9ed3:153)
    at CKFinderCommand.eval (observablemixin.js?3466:268)
    at CKFinderCommand.fire (emittermixin.js?e4c7:236)
    at CKFinderCommand.(:9191/anonymous function) [as execute] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/observablemixin.js:296:19)
    at CommandCollection.execute (commandcollection.js?e961:92)
    at ClassicEditor.execute (editor.js?7e01:299)
    at ButtonView.eval (ckfinderui.js?8a75:47)
    at ButtonView.fire (emittermixin.js?e4c7:236)
    at TemplateToBinding.eval (buttonview.js?d175:167)
    at ProxyEmitter.callback (template.js?56c1:1208)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach CKFinder to your page first, so CKEditor 5 can use it.

The easiest way to do so is by using a script tag:

```
<script src="https://example.com/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

More information: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html#configuring-the-full-integration